# cap products and injective abelian groups

Tags: homological-algebra

There is a result in Cartan Eilenberg (XII 6.4) that says that if $G$ is a finite group and $D$ a divisible abelian group with trivial $G$-action then for any $G$-module $M$ the cup product $$\widehat{H}^{r-1}(G,Hom(M,D)) \times \widehat{H}^{-r}(G,M) \longrightarrow \widehat{H}^{-1}(G,D)$$ induces an isomorphism $$\widehat{H}^{r-1}(G,Hom(M,D)) \longrightarrow Hom(\widehat{H}^{-r}(G,M),D)$$ for all $r \in \mathbb{Z}$

I wanted to know if this result would hold for non-Tate cohomology and homology groups, i.e.,
if instead of having a finite group $G$, we used an arbitrary group $G$ and instead of using cup products we used cap products, would the result still hold for all $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ or maybe for some $r$?

Thank you

Comment: This is a comment. But I'm not able to comment on your question, so I'm posting these questions as answer: 1. What do you mean by "non-Tate cohomology and homology groups" ? 2. How is $\hat{H}^{-r}(G,M)$ defined if $r> 0$ and $G$ is an arbitrary group ?

Comment: Non-Tate surely means the usual homology and cohomology of a group.

Comment: For arbitrary groups neither the OP not I talked about Tate cohomology, btw.

Comment: Yeah by non-Tate I just ment usual homology and cohomology groups, this is why I was wondering about cap-products as they seem to work more generally than the cup-product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isomorphism, at least, exists. Take $M\leftarrow Y$  and $\mathbb Z\leftarrow X$  projective resolutions of $M$ and of $\mathbb Z$ as $G$-modules. The double complex $\hom_G(X,\hom_{\mathbb Z}(Y,D))$ gives rise, as usual, to two spectral sequences. Computing first cohomology with respect to the differential induced by that of $Y$ and then by that of $X$, we get $H^\bullet(G,\hom(M,D))$. On the other hand, rewriting the complex as $\hom_{\mathbb Z}(Y\otimes_G X,D)$ using standard adjunctions, and then computing homology first with respect to the differential induced by that of $X$ and then by that of $Y$ gives the other side of your isomorphism. Convergence then does the trick.

That the isorphism is given by cap products should follow from general nonsense...

Comment: This does what you want for *half* the $r$; I guess something similar will take care of the other half.

Comment: (And, as usual, this can be rephrased in the language of derived categories and friends —I am old-fashioned that way... :-) )

Comment: Thank you very much, I need to compute this in detail for r=2, can you recomend a good source to read up on spectral sequences, given that I dont know much about them

Comment: MacCleary's book has a pretty straightforward exposition; since you are already reading Cartan-Eilenberg, that's also readable (this is a somewhat unpopular opinion, though!) Weibel has a nice exposition too.

Comment: You say the isomorphism exists. But which isomorphism ? All your complexes ($X, Y$ and the various hom's thereof) are positive. Can you please explain how the complex $\hom_{\mathbb Z}(Y\otimes_G X,D)$ leads to cohomology in negative degrees ? 

Comment: The isomorphism is given by a composition of edge morphisms in the two spectral sequences; this can be explicitly computed easily, and will give the obvious map which generalizes the map in degree zero one can guess. As for «negative degrees», I don't know what you mean.

Comment: In Chris' question there is only one isomorphims, namely 
$$\widehat{H}^{r-1}(G,Hom(M,D)) \longrightarrow Hom(\widehat{H}^{-r}(G,M),D)$$ According to your answer, by the first spectral sequence corresponding to the double complex $\hom_G(X,\hom_{\mathbb Z}(Y,D))$ "we get $H^\bullet(G,\hom(M,D))$" and the second spectral sequence "gives the other side of your isomorphism." But the other side is $Hom(\widehat{H}^{-r}(G,M),D)$ where $-r$ is negative if $r>0$. This is what I mean by "negative degrees". Your spectral sequences don't cover these negative degrees since they are in first quadrant. 

Comment: As I wrote above, the argument I described gives half the isomorphisms; the rest can be obtained from a similar spectral sequence. Tate cohomology in negative degrees is essentially just group *homology*; the indexing works out correctly to get what is wanted.

Comment: Mariano, aren't the arguments you used for the 2nd ss enough to prove the isomorphism altogether? For,  
$$\hom_G(X,\hom(M,D))\cong \hom_G(X\otimes M,D)\cong \hom(X\otimes_G M,D)$$
yields $H^i(G,\hom(M,D))\cong \hom(H_i(G,M),D)$ for $i \ge 0$. 

Comment: With respect to the other half of the isomorphisms, I'm not very positive: Let $M=D=\mathbb{Q}$ and write $(-)'$ for the dual of a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. If you expect something like $H_\ast(G,\mathbb{Q})\cong \hom(H^\ast(G,\mathbb{Q}),\mathbb{Q})$, then, by composing with the iso. above, you'll get $H_\ast(G,\mathbb{Q}) \cong (H_\ast(G,\mathbb{Q})''$. But this will be wrong if $H_\ast(G,\mathbb{Q})$ has infinite dimension! 

Comment: @Ralph, indeed, I should have mentioned that some sort of finiteness condition is needed for the other duality. You are right that my ss argument is a bit too nuclear ---it is the argument needed to deal with general $D$, where the end result is a spectral sequence and not an isomorphism.

Comment: @Ralph: I'm pretty new at spectral sequences, I was wondering about your first comment, where you talk about the isomorphism for $i \geq 0$, where does the fact that D is a divisible abelian group come in?

Comment: @Chris, D is a divisible abelian group iff it is an injective abelian group iff $\hom(\mathord−,D)$ is an eexact functor. This is where the fact comees in

Comment: @Mariano, yeah I know this, I was just wondering on which side of the isomorphism is it being used, or is it on both? 

Comment: Having said that, this might be a silly question, sorry

Comment: Chris, I'm sorry, I saw your question 4 comments above just now. The isomorphism of complexes $\hom_G(X,\hom(M,D))\cong \hom(X\otimes_G M,D)$ holds for all $D$. Taking (co)homology yields $H^n(G,\hom(M,D)) \cong H^n(\hom(X\otimes_G M,D))$. If $D$ is divisible, then $\hom(-,D)$ is exact (as explained by Mariano). The point is now that exact functors commute with (co)homology, i.e. $H^n(\hom(X\otimes_G M,D))\cong \hom(H_n(X\otimes_G M),D)=\hom(H_n(G,M),D)$. 